# Add app model in new Page by drop-down select in Django

Tags: django, dynamic, drop-down-menu, model

It is bit complicated so I hope that explain this properly.
I have app which is created within new Page in admin site. In that app I have also drop-down list with my installed apps like on picture.

[drop-down of installed apps in new Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7dhn.png)

I need someway to add models of selected app dynamicaly by add button at the end of this Page. So if I select app, with add button add model of app below page content, next select second app and add model below app added before. So at the end I will have filled Page with models of apps that I added.
Adding functionality like on this picture or with some add button or add button next to drop-down.

[desired functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEq0G.png)

I dont have so much experiences in Django that I can make it self right now. I know that this is possible but I need help of you that you are Django Pro. I really need to make this done.